# Mechanism of reaction of alcohol with NaBr + H2SO4

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

My teacher told that the mechanism for reaction of alcohol with $\ce{NaBr + H2SO4}$ follows S<sub>N</sub>1 when alcohol is 2°/3° and S<sub>N</sub>2 when it is primary or methanol. He told that the reactivity of alcohol also follows the order 3° > 2° > 1° which is that of S<sub>N</sub>1.

But I couldn't understand why is it the case. The nucleophile is $\ce{Br-},$ which is anionic nucleophile—so it should always follow S<sub>N</sub>2.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deb , it's not just NaBr , it's NaBr + H2SO4 , which would protonate the -OH group into a good leaving group.

Comment: Primary alcohols will form primary carbocation which is not very stable , also the nucleophile here is a strong anionic nucleophile which would favour SN2 .

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Read carefully the post you linked. OP's teacher is right.

Comment: OH is a poor leaving group. After protonation, it gets converted to one of the best leaving groups which leave the substrate immediately. This results in a carbocation

Comment: Can people _please_ stop proposing primary and methyl cations in their mechanisms?